# Converting curl request to Node JS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I am having an issue, here is my working curl request:

```
curl "https://api.com/v1/listings?_expand=PrimaryPhoto&_filter=&_page=1&_pagination=1" -H "X-SparkApi-User-Agent: SparkAPIExamples" -H "Authorization: OAuth 12345" {}
```

Here is my node js request that does not seem to work, I have no access to the logs from the API side so I am unable to truly see what is being received on the other end.

```
exports.show = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user.spark);
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;
    var options = {
        host: 'www.api.com',
        path: '/v1/listings?_expand=PrimaryPhoto&_filter=&_page=1&_pagination=1',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'OAuth 12345', "X-SparkApi-User-Agent": "SparkAPIExamples"}
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
      var completeResponse = '';
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
          completeResponse += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end', function() {
        res.send(completeResponse);
      });
    };

    https.request(options, callback).end();
}
```

The API throws an error stating my access token (the 12345) is wrong, which makes me think however it is formatting that portion of the header is incorrect.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mock out the foreign API so you can see what is received at the other end?

Comment: Good idea, not sure why i didnt think about doing that.

Comment: I was able to mock out the API using HTTP and the requests are practically identical, updated the few discrepancies and the results are the same.  I am not specifying certificates for either my curl request or my node js request, so I am not sure what it is using for the HTTPS.